# Visual Studio Work Account Login Re-Enter Loop

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

In VS2017, VS2019, and VS2022 our developers have been having significant issues with Visual Studio logging in with their company emails (Office 365 accounts - Visual Studio access granted that way).

This is encountered in both the Visual Studio Account Settings pane and the Azure New Publish Profile window. They successfully log in (uname, pword, and 2FA), and then within a second or two they are asked to re-enter credentials. We have seen this happen frequently over the past year or so over multiple VS versions (both before and after fresh installs), multiple computers (both before and after a complete windows wipe and reinstall), and with every developer on staff. (I personally have seen it happen upwards of 8 times in a row before the program decided to keep it).

Does anybody know what is going on with this, and if there is any way to stop (or even mitigate - we'll take what we can get at this point) this from happening?

[Example "Re-Enter Credentials" screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW2wJ.png)

Comment: To be clear, the credentials are your AD credentials for the company and they are also the accounts used to provision the "Visual Studio Subscription" for the developer(s)?

Comment: As far as I am aware, yes. Our Visual Studio Subscription and our work emails and our Office 365 accounts are all the same.

Comment: Which 2FA is being used? Is it onsite or cloud?

Comment: 2FA is the Microsoft Authenticator, and our company is 100% remote, so Cloud I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the accounts have access to multiple tenants which also have 2FA? From my experience the re-enter credentials loop is to cycle through tenants which enforce 2FA. If you go to account settings and amend the 'Apply filter...' to just the tenant you are working on then it should only ask for the credentials to be validated once.

Comment: I can check for that, thanks for the potential workaround, however after updating to Visual Studio 2022 we have seen the issue far less - it generally only happens if we go to look if we're logged into the program. We can generally build, publish, etc without having to do the log in cycle every time. (before VS2022, we had to do the cycle every time we wanted to publish - now it's only for one project, about once a month it will pop a WinXP era "log in" dialog, but none of our Azure creds work for it. Logging in to VS2022 and fetching new xpub from Azure makes the dialog no longer appear.

Answer (score 4):

try this solution -> https://blog.jongallant.com/2021/08/visual-studio-re-enter-credentials/

if not work, uncheck the checkbox, then try again (this solved my problem)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have 2fa on for my Microsoft account but what was happening was I  was  using the same email account for  3 azure  tenants and one of them was failing.

After I deleted the c:\Users\**YOURUSERNAME**\AppData\Local\.IdentityService
folder (I am on Windows10) and signed back in to Visual Studio 2017, I finally saw the dialog box stating that my account wasn't authorized for one of my tenants. However, it wasn't the tenant that hosted my Azure App service website.

After i started seeing the correct message, I signed back into Visual Studio but it took me a few times of closing VS app and coming back in to finally get the "signed in" status for my account.

After the status for Visual Studio was "signed in" I select FILTERED  for the tenant that was hosting my app service website and it  worked.

Also, here is the solution provided for Visual Studio 2019 and greater from Microsoft.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/improving-the-authentication-experience-for-enterprises-leveraging-conditional-access-policies/